# How to make validator's message appear nearby another control?

Tags: asp.net

I have a validator with a bound text field (it's set via ControlToValidate). How can I make the validator's error message appear nearby another control (a label above this text field)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the validator control nearby the control where you want to show the message i.e. wherever you want to show the message just put the validator control there.

In the following example I am showing validation message near some other control not near the text box.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Label ID="lblNameRequired" runat="server" Text="*Name :"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNameRequired" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Validation"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblGenderRequired" runat="server" Text="*Gender :"></asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGenderRequired" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Validation">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="-1">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">Male</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Female</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidatorGender" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlGenderRequired"
    Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Gender is Required" Operator="NotEqual" ValidationGroup="Validation"
    ValueToCompare="-1"></asp:CompareValidator>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblValidation" runat="server" Text="Fields marked with * are required"></asp:Label>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNameRequired"
    Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Name is Required" ValidationGroup="Validation"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnValidate" runat="server" Text="Validate Input" ValidationGroup="Validation" />
<br />
</form>
```

Hope this helps you.